# Constructors for subclasses

Tags: java, constructor, subclass

Okay guys, im having trouble with these constructors for this code and some logic. I did most of it, just confused on how to finish this off.

Here is the main code i have. (it might be a little sloppy but its "good enough")

```
public class Accountdrv {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Account account = new Account(1122, 20000, 4.5);

    account.withdraw(2500);
    account.deposit(3000);
    System.out.println("Balance is " + account.getBalance());
    System.out.println("Monthly interest is " +
      account.getMonthlyInterest());
    System.out.println("This account was created at " +
      account.getDateCreated());
  }
}

class Account {
  private int id;
  private double balance;
  private double annualInterestRate;
  private java.util.Date dateCreated;

  public Account() {
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
  }

  public Account(int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate) {
    this.id = id;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
  }

  public int getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
  }

  public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
    return annualInterestRate;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id =id;
  }

  public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
  }

  public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
  }

  public double getMonthlyInterest() {
    return balance * (annualInterestRate / 1200);
  }

  public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
  }

  public void withdraw(double amount) {
    balance -= amount;
  }

  public void deposit(double amount) {
    balance += amount;
  }
}
```

Now, i wanted to create a Savings, and Checking account. I need help with what i need to add for constructors, i put in the comments the parts i know im missing but confused on how to do them.

Savings:

```
class Savings extends Account{
//need to create a constructor
  public Savings(int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate) {
//need to invoke the constructor for Account
  super(id, balance, annualInterestRate);
 }

// need to override the withdraw method in Account
public void withdraw(double amount) {
    // place logic to prevent the account from being overdrawn
    // that is do not allow a negative balance
  }
}
```

Comment: This must be homework. A real bank would add logic to charge a fee, not prevent the account from being overdrawn.  ;)

Comment: @BilltheLizard haha yeah it is homework xb .. best place to go for help and questions.. soo.. yeah c:

Comment: Any reason why you don't just import java.util.Date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check id the amount < balance Or whatever logic you have (eg: you want 
some threshold amount to be present in the account).

Also I would recommend to look into synchronized methods as you should synchronize access to account of a given user to ensure that when a withdraw function is invoked...another withdraw on the same user account has to wait...or else it will lead to problems...I will leave that to you to figure out.

```
public void withdraw(double amount) {
// place logic to prevent the account from being overdrawn
// that is do not allow a negative balance

     if(balance < amount)
     {
        // print error message or do something
     }
     else
     {
        // withdraw the money
        balance -= amount;
        // print message or do something
     }
}
```

Comment: @Ryan what other query do you have ?

Comment: oh so the constructors look good? xD i felt like i did something wrong, or less sufficient or something.

Comment: Compile the code and let me know if you have any issues

Answer (score 1):

`super()` invokes the constructor for the super-class, in the `Savings` case, `Account`.

Comment: do i need  `super(id, balance, annualInterestRate);` or can i just use `super();` ?

Comment: @Ryan You need the arguments, it is the constructor. Unless you have a constructor with no parameters you need to pass it arguments.